# How filter queryset with a calculation?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have a model similar to

```
class House:
    x = IntegerField()
    y = IntegerField()
```

I want to return the houses that are at a smaller distance that *distance* from some position using the following calculation:

```
abs(house.x - myPos.x) + abs(house.y - myPos.y) < distance
```

But I don't know how to make that filter since filter() only compares with a model's field. I would like to do something like:

```
House.objects.filter(abs(x - myPos.x) + abs(y - myPos.y) < distance)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution for this problem can be resolved in 2 steps:

1. Annotate `abs(x - myPos.x) + abs(y - myPos.y)` expression
2. Compare annotated expression with `distance` value

In order to annotate the expression Django ORM supports [func expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) who provide database functions like **COALESCE**, **LOWER**, **SUM**, **ABS** and many other.

For your example you can use this query:

```
from django.db.models import Func, F
House.objects.annotate(abs_calculation=Func(F('x') - myPos.x, function='ABS') + Func(F('y') - myPos.y, function='ABS')).filter(abs_calculation__lt=distance)
```

Comment: Perfect! I saw all theses things but I wasn't able to put them together. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I have one more question, just in case you know. If my model has a manytomany relationship (for example x and y are located on an object Location), can I use F() to access them? For example something like F("location.x")? (I tried this and it doesn't work)

Comment: OK, I found I can use F("location__x") type of notation for other ManyToMany relationships, but in my case I realized that I have a PointField, so that's why it is not working.

Comment: You don't need many-to-many relation with Location because one house can only be on one location, there cannot be multiple locations for single house. You basically need ForeignKey relation with Location and in that situation I would try with F('location__x')